TLS 1.3 Negotiation Issue - Inconsistent Behavior Based on PCAP Timing

Client: Supports only TLS 1.3

Server: Initially configured to support only TLS 1.2, then upgraded to support TLS 1.3

Inconsistent behavior observed based on PCAP timing:

If I start the service and then start the PCAP, all messages are in TLS 1.3 as expected.

If I restart the service and then start the PCAP, I see TLS 1.2 traffic.




What I've Tried:

On the server side, I've configured it to support only TLS 1.2.

On the client side, I've made it support only TLS 1.3.

When starting the service, no handshake occurs because the client only supports TLS 1.3.

I've then upgraded the server to support TLS 1.3.

After the upgrade, the negotiation happens, and application data is sent, but the same scenario occurs:

If I restart the service and then start the PCAP, I see TLS 1.2 traffic.

Before restarting the PCAP, I see TLS 1.3 traffic.




Note: I was not able to perform sslscan on my application, it uses ephemeral port.
Is this the expected behavior for TLS 1.3? I've reviewed the RFC but couldn't find much information on this.

"I see ...." - what do you look at in the first place? Please show what you actually have instead of only providing your interpretation of what is happening.

TLS has at least two distinct version numbers: outer (record) and inner (handshake). The outer version number is visible in clear on all TLS packet types, while the inner version is only seen during the handshake. (And even the latter is fixed in this case; the use of version 1.3 is determined by other handshake parameters than the version field.)
Because of past experience with shortsighted firewalls that did not recognize newer versions, TLS v1.3 uses the same record structure and version number as TLS v1.2 – if you look at the packet contents, you will always see the same "Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)" in every record. In other words, after the handshake has finished, further packets are indistinguishable between the two versions to an outside viewer.
So you're seeing exactly the same traffic, but your capture viewer (Wireshark) infers a different version from the handshake if it is captured (i.e. the TLS dissector keeps state), whereas without the handshake it has no choice but to believe the per-record version number.
